# Nice looking empty set?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, typography

I feel like the standard `$\emptyset$` is ugly. By hand, my empty set symbol is a lot rounder, then this "slashed-zero"-type symbol.

Two questions:

- Do people really use it (I mean people who have any sort of sense of aesthetics)?
- What alternatives do you suggest?

I seem to recall something closer to what I'm looking for - a slash round-o - but the diameter of the circle seemed too small, I think. (And am I asking this in the right place?)

Comment: I use `\emptyset` and don't like `\varnothing`, which is  more a symbol for plumbers than mathematicians. :) Michael's advice is pretious: `\renewcommand{\emptyset}{...}` or `\let\emptyset\???`, so that you can easily change your mind.

Comment: Regarding first question. Go to [LaTeX Search](http://latexsearch.com/) and search for `\emptyset`. You'll get ~1000 docs using it (it is possibly a search limit), so I dare to say it is used.

Comment: egreg: tomayto, tomawto ;-)

Comment: przemoc: you don't account for poor taste (said jokingly - mostly!).

Comment: @Jérémie: If you want to reach particular commentator, i.e. be sure it will be notified about it, you have to precede username (at least using 3 first unambiguous characters) with `@`. Read [details](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets-n) regarding it. BTW here I didn't have to address you directly, as you're the OP, so you would be notified anyway.

Comment: I am few years late, but I do use this macro:
\newcommand{\eset}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\textrm{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\smaller[0.5]\O}}}} to use the letter Ø.

Comment: @egreg Do you mean that N. Bourbaki was an anonymous group of plumbers with A. Weil as a CEO? ,-)

Comment: @Denis I mean that Bourbaki's books are full of bad notation, not just the plumber's symbol. WIth due respect to the members of the group.

Comment: @egreg de gustibus non est disputandum. This being said, I'm French and I was raised with Bourbaki's notation. Hence `\varnothing` seems perfectly right to me whereas `\emptyset` looks quite weird.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Try `\varnothing` from the `amssymb` package. It is perfectly round, and the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list states that it is preferred by many to `\emptyset`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\let\oldemptyset\emptyset
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\begin{document}
$\oldemptyset$ $\emptyset$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly the answer that I was looking for.

Comment: Can we all agree that \phi and \Phi should never be used for this?  Argh! ;-)

Comment: @ColinFraizer I can't believe it. Do people seriously use Phi for empty set? Shocking!

Comment: Just wait until someone sees `\phi` and doesn't understand it's meant to be "empty set", and uses `\varphi` in his own documents. My engineering textbook was a nightmare.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández Unfortunately, yes. [In the wild](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_r9NwiKQbE#t=243)… (video should start at 4:03; offending statement at 4:17).

Comment: @WChargin my eyes!

Comment: Interestingly, in mathjax, `\emptyset` and `\varnothing` are exactly the other way around :-P

Comment: thanks to the answer for also demonstrating the let statement

Comment: This will not work in XeTeX + unicode-math package -- see [amssymb - Empty set symbols confused - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208014/250119)

Comment: `\varnothing` is indeed preferred to `\emptyset` by plumbers, who are more than mathematicians.

Answer (score 29):

I always just use "\O" in math mode:

```
$\O$
```

[image]

Comment: I used to do this, but LaTeX issues a warning if you do this. As such, I prefer `\varnothing`.

Comment: @ArunDebray, this must be what you're referring to: `LaTeX Warning: Command \O invalid in math mode on input line 1006`. I have so many warnings in my thesis document I don't even notice unless the output halts. Output does look fine though.

Comment: @freb Ignoring LaTeX warnings is a way to disaster...

Comment: Note that Ø (aka \O) is the true origin of the symbol (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29364/1913) ). To avoid the warnings, you can use the amsmath package and \text{\O} (or  \text{Ø} if you use latin1 or utf8 encoding, plus a keyboard giving access to this letter). If you tired to type \text everywhere, \newcommand is your friend

Comment: IMHO, still the sexiest empty set on this page.

Comment: @yo' meh, I'm sure it depends on your use case. I wrote a 50+ page thesis with a million compiler errors but the resulting pdf was exactly what I wanted. So do I spend a few hours just to get clean compiler output? Do we serve the compiler or does it serve us?

Answer (score 9):

I find that  { } (`\{\}` in LateX) is perfectly clear to mathematicians, maybe not to computer scientists. 
I would use the following:

[image]

This is obtained with

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $myset \gets \{\}$
        \For{$i = 0\, \textbf{to}\, 4$}
            \State {$myset\gets myset\, ||\, (4 - i)$}\Comment{append $i$-th reversed index}
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Using `\emptyset` would give

[image]
This is obtained with

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[2]    
    \State $myset \gets \emptyset$
        \For{$i = 0\, \textbf{to}\, 4$}
            \State {$myset\gets myset\, ||\, (4 - i)$}\Comment{append $i$-th reversed index}
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Why would computer scientists shun from {}. Most are fluent in some programming language(s), and that's the most common syntax for an empty collection. I always figured it would be the other way around.

Comment: @Xi'an  Sorry you fail to see. The questions were:
    Do people really use it (I mean people who have any sort of sense of aesthetics)?
    What alternatives do you suggest?

Comment: The question is about finding a more pleasing rendering of the empty set than `\ emptyset`, not using another symbol that is not commonly used in mathematics. The first and most voted answer brings a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Do you really understand that from the question? Amazing the people one can meet on the Internet. In any case, I won't comment on this anymore, other readers can judge, if it worth their time.

Comment: @Neowizard In Python, both dictionaries and sets are created with braces, so they had to decide what `{}` meant and they made it the empty dictionary (though `dict()` achieves the same). Anyone familiar with Python, or any other language that made `{}` something other than a set, would have that as a reason for shunning `{}` as a synonym for the empty set in mathematics or Python's `set()`.

Comment: @Neowizard Fine, _could_ have that as a reason. As a fellow Python dev, I don't shun that notation for an empty set either.

Answer (score 4):

The `\diameter` is an alternative for `emptyset` in lines, it is a bit tiny.

```
\usepackage{wasysym}
\emptyset\diameter
```

[image: emptyset vs diameter]

Comment: diameter is another symbol, which is intended for ... diameters in mechanical engineering, plumbing, etc.