# Empty set symbols confused

Tags: amssymb

I am trying to typeset the symbol for empty set and using the answer of [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22798/nice-looking-empty-set) I chose `\varnothing` but when I used it I got the symbol that is described to be `\emptyset` and vice versa. Also when I use the `amssymb` package I get these errors:

```
Command `\eth' already defined.

Command `\digamma' already 

Command `\backepsilon' already
```

If I don't use`amssymb` it still happens the same regarding those 2 symbols. What is happening? How can I get the right symbol? (Meaning the `\varnothing`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont
[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

This is the problem:

\vspace{1cm}

$\varnothing \quad \emptyset$

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should post a minimal compilable example, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok I will edit my question.

Comment: Now your question looks better. It seems that, by default `\emptyset` and `\varnothing` output the same symbol with `unicode-math`.

Comment: [Related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125175/how-to-get-xelatex-unicode-math-output-as-close-as-possible-to-that-of-pdfla).

Comment: See also http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are not two distinct Unicode points for the empty set and its variant symbol (they are just different forms of the same symbol). Find a font that has the circle form and use it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
]{GFSArtemisia}

%\setsansfontMapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf} %%% it's not sans serif!

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

This is the problem: $\varnothing\subseteq A\times B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, Latin Modern Math together with GFS Artemisia doesn't seem too nice a combination. If your document is math intensive, Artemisia for the Latin characters is not recommendable, in my opinion, because there's no matching math font.

Loading Latin Modern Math explicitly is necessary if another math font is chosen for some range of characters (it's a bug of `fontspec`, I'd say).

Note that, depending on the host system (say ShareLaTeX or WriteLaTeX) or your own system, the font may have to be loaded by file name and not by font name; in this case, the math fonts should be loaded with

```
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}
```

Comment: Another thing that annoys me is the necessity of calling `range=\int` (or whatever) to get the correct “dimensions”. Wouldn't it be more clear if `range=\varnothing` imported nothing else but `\varnothing`?

Comment: @Manuel It's really annoying. Let's hope these bugs will be fixed soon.

Comment: @egreg thank you I will try it! Can you please explain to me why except the first `\setmathfont` there are two more?

Comment: @Adam The first and third `\setmathfont` shouldn't be necessary in an ideal world (Latin Modern Math is the default of `unicode-math`), but they're unfortunately needed if different fonts are used for some ranges. With only the second declaration, two bugs of `unicode-math` show, which are corrected with the other two declarations. The order matters.

Comment: @egreg I used these lines of code and I get errors: Undefined control sequence.
l.37 \setmathfont {Latin Modern Math}
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
Undefined control sequence.
l.38 \setmathfont[range=\varnothing ]{Asana Math}
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>

Comment: @Adam Please, upgrade your TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg I use ShareLatex so it is upgraded. :)

Comment: @Adam Not sure it is. Look in the log file for the version of `unicode-math`

Comment: @egreg where can I find it?

Comment: @Adam In the log file; look for `unicode-math` and the version number will be next to it. Sorry, but I won't register just for this.

Comment: @egreg It says unicode-math 2014/06/30 v0.7f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18026/discussion-between-egreg-and-adam).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the "msb" (?) font which is what is being used when `amssymb` package is loaded without `unicode-math`.

Just open `amssymb.sty` and `amsfonts.sty` and copy the 2 lines, change `\varnothing` to `\varnothingold`.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}  % not needed with \usepackage{amsfonts} or \usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varnothingold}     {\mathord}{AMSb}{"3F}
\begin{document}
$\varnothing$
$\varnothingold$
\end{document}
```

Output: [image: Output image]

---

Yet another way is to use the New Computer Modern font, which looks similar to the "default TeX math font", except that it has a `cv01` character table (or CharacterVariant=1 option) that selects the rounded variant of the `∅` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

$\emptyset$
\setmathfont[CharacterVariant=1]{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}
$\emptyset$

\end{document}
```

Output is same as the above.