# How to see the \O in math-mode (at LyX)

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I'm using LyX 2.1.2 and when I put (at math-mode) this: `\O` I see nothing at the pdf file.
Do you know why?

If this helps - when I look at the source code - this what I see:
`\L{$\O$}`
But when I put it at ERT: `$\O$` there is no problem and I see it at the pdf file....

Thank you!

Here is the source code of the file:

```
%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\L{$\O$} -

$\O$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want `\emptyset`, not `\O`; or `\varnothing` from `amssymb`.

Comment: sorry there is a `\makeatletter` hiding some lines above. i deleted previous comment.

Comment: @egreg ,Yes, but `\emptyset` and `\varnothing` are different from `\O` (they similar but not the same). There is any way to put it at math-mode? (the `\O`).

Comment: You really want the scandanavian letter? what does Ø mean in math that is different to `\emptyset` ??? How will your readers know the difference?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, even the Scandinavian letter is very pretty, I look for a symbol for the **empty set**. I know there is few options, and the `\O` is one of them (fix me if I'm wrong)... I saw this question and I agree with the person who ask it...
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22798/nice-looking-empty-set

Comment: using \O for the empty set is wrong, it is the text letter O with stroke, any similarity with emptyset is accidental. you probably want `\varnothing`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - You answerd my question! Thank you!!  (Maybe I'll use now the `\varnothing` - if it's mean the empty set also...

Comment: Actually not accidentally, the symbol for the empty set originated from the Scandinavian ø (the originator was French, I think, and he knew some Norwegian). But nowadays, especially in latex, special math symbols are used, not the `\O` as it is a text only symbol.

Comment: @daleif i did wonder if my comment was totally historically accurate:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Barbara recently emailed me in relation to some unicode about empty set and ø. I then asked a math historian. He even sent me a scan of on of the first (presumably) printed book that was using the symbol. It was clearly a lower case ø. I think the book was from 1939.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thank you for the interesting information!! :-)

Comment: @daleif - Thank you for your comment! It's very interesting!! If you can put it here (the scan from 1939) it will be very nice :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `\emptyset`, not `\O`; or `\varnothing` from `amssymb`.

Comment: As you write me at the comments to my qestion (_"using \O for the empty set is wrong, it is the text letter O with stroke, any similarity with emptyset is accidental."_), `\O` is not a symbol of the empty set at all, so yes, I will use `\emptyset` or `\varnothing` for the empty set :-)

Comment: @Yoar: Insert > Math > Inline Math > Miscellaneous > emptyset.

Comment: @Werner, where? I don't find it.... I saw: Insert > Math > Inline Math (at LyX), But I didn't found the next levels....

Comment: @Yoar: Miscellaneous is part of the math object menu. Here are some images to light the way: Insert > Math > Inline Math > [Miscellaneous](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OKnec.png) > [emptyset](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ll7B5.png)

Comment: Actually the letter Ø is indeed the symbol. Check it here: http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html look for "The null set symbol."

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzonino  Ø is U+00d8 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE  which is `\O` in latex, the empty set is ∅  U+2205 EMPTY SET     &empty; &emptyset; &emptyv; &varnothing; \varnothing